connecting GSM module to VU of nodemcu
can i connect VCC pin of GSM module to VU of nodemcu? i have a code to send sms using GSM and esp8266. but it never send. the output of serial monitor is:

Waiting 10 seconds to send SMS...
Sending SMS...
---> AT+CMGF=1
<--- ERROR
SMS not sent!
Waiting 10 seconds to send SMS...
Sending SMS...

and my code is:
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Adafruit_FONA.h>

#define FONA_RX D3
#define FONA_TX D4
#define FONA_RST D5 // Define FONA_RST pin

SoftwareSerial mySerial(FONA_RX, FONA_TX);
Adafruit_FONA fona = Adafruit_FONA(FONA_RST); // Initialize FONA object with the software serial port

void setup() {
    pinMode(FONA_RST, OUTPUT); // Set FONA_RST pin as OUTPUT
    digitalWrite(FONA_RST, HIGH); // Reset FONA
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(FONA_RST, LOW);
    delay(1000); // Wait for FONA to initialize

    Serial.begin(9600);
    mySerial.begin(9600); // Set the baud rate to 9600
    if (!fona.begin(mySerial)) {
        Serial.println(F("Couldn't find FONA"));
        while (1);
    }
    Serial.println(F("FONA is OK"));
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println(F("Waiting 10 seconds to send SMS..."));
    delay(10000);
    Serial.println(F("Sending SMS..."));
    char phoneNumber[] = "+989333639888"; // Define phoneNumber as char array
    char message[] = "Hello from NodeMCU!"; // Define message as char array
    if (fona.sendSMS(phoneNumber, message)) {
        Serial.println(F("SMS sent!"));
    } else {
        Serial.println(F("SMS not sent!"));
    }
    delay(60000); // Wait 60 seconds before sending another SMS
}

when i type and send any AT command in serial interface of Arduino ide nothing happen.
